# Multiple datepickers on same form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Multiple datepickers on same form 
Check out my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/83xzT/1/

I have the form adding additional lines as needed and I can get the date picker to work on the first input. However, my attempt to add an additional input to each using a count i and appending the instance name is not working.

any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix, just move

```
$("#datepicker" + i).datepicker();
```

into the

```
 $('#add').click(function() {
   ....
 }
```

block, right above the i++;  Next is to get rid if your if/else blocks and just have it run

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

on document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `$("#datepicker" + i).datepicker();` inside the click function

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/83xzT/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a class instead of an id on the field:

```
<input type="text" name="date[]" class="field" class="datepicker" value=""/>
```

Then change your add function like this:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('... html tags ...').appendTo('.inputs').fadeIn('slow', function() {
       $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
http://jsfiddle.net/83xzT/8/

```
    var i = 1;
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

$('#add').click(function() {
    $('<div><span class="fieldset"><input type="text" name="date[]" class="field" id="datepicker' + i + '" value=""/> <select class="field" name="time[]"><option value="NULL">---Select Time ---</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option></select> <select class="field" name="timeframe[]"><option value="NULL">---Select A.M/P.M. ---</option><option value="am">A.M.</option><option value="pm">P.M.</option></select><input type="hidden" name="breaker[]" class="field" value=";"/></span></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
        if(i >= 1) {
            $( "#datepicker" + i ).datepicker();
        }
    i++;
});
```